# ID in mongoose make visible in the web page

Tags: node.js, database, express, mongoose, ejs

I am trying to make the req.params.id visible to the web page but I do not know how to execute it properly. I am new in mongoose so bear with me hehe

EDITED: This is my code for the question that I want to have a solution

`router.get('/stockIn/:id', shopController.getFlowerStockIn);`

```
exports.getFlowerStockIn = (req,res,next) => {

    Stocks.findOne({id: req.params.id})
        .then(stock => {
            console.log('stocks', stock)
            res.render('stock-in', {stockIn: stock});
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err)); 
   
}
```

`router.post('/stock-in', stocksController.postStockInAmount);`

This is where I want to apply my problem

```
exports.postStockInAmount = (req,res,next) => {

const qty = Number(req.body.quantity)
const addStockIn = Number (req.body.stockIn)

    Stocks.findOneAndUpdate(
        {id: req.params.id}, 
        {}, 
        {new: true}, (err, cd) => {

                
            const stock = new Stocks ({
                id: req.body.id,
                flowerName: req.body.flowerName,
                quantity: (qty + addStockIn)
             
            });
            stock.save()
                .then(result => {
                    res.redirect('flowers-in-stock');
                }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    )
    
}
```

Problem:

[image]

This is how incrementing works in my code

```
exports.postFlower = (req,res,next) => {
    
    Counter.findOneAndUpdate(
        {id: "autoval"}, 
        {"$inc":{"seq": 1}}, 
        {new: true}, (err, cd) => {


            let seqID;
            if(cd==null) {
                const newValue = new Counter({id: "autoval", seq:1})
                newValue.save() 
                seqID = 1
            } else { 
                seqID = cd.seq
            }

            const qty = Number(req.body.quantity)
            
           
            const stock = new Stocks ({
                id: seqID,
                flowerName: req.body.flowerName,
                quantity: req.body.quantity
                
            })
            stock.save()
                .then(result => {
                    res.redirect('flowers-in-stock');
                }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Does the `console.log('stocks', stock)` print out correctly ?

Comment: Yes, it prints out correctly

Comment: Then your first code is correct, I still don't know what problem you're facing

Comment: I just put the first code so that you can understand everything haha. Kindly look the image that I uploaded, I want to happen is when I add another quantity the same Flower# will appear in the 2nd row but in here, it doesn't appear :<

Comment: Actually, I have a counter which is an auto increment id whenever I add a document, it automatically increment the id

Comment: Do you want to update the existing or create a new one ?

Comment: I want to update the existing with creating a new row because that's what we need to do :(

Comment: I updated my post, I added my auto increment id whenever adding a flowerName and quantity

Comment: @hungtran273 is it possible to create a new one with the same id number based on my code?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access URL parameters it has to be done within a route. E.g.

```
router.get('/flowers/:id', async (req, res) => {
    await Stocks.findOneAndUpdate(
            {id: req.params.id},
    ...
})
```

Furthermore, anytime req.xx.yy is used you are requesting information once a request has been made to the API.
So from the frontend it would look like:

```
axios.get(`http://0.0.0.0:PORT/flowers/${flowerID}`) 
.then((response) => {})
```

Comment: Kindly look to my edited version, I provided my whole code for that function